# Jquery .animate wont work

Tags: jquery, html

Not sure why but I am desperately trying to get this example of a jquery fade in I found on jsfiddle to work with my site...however I can't get my site to work... in the head of my page I link to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js and after that I link to the file I have my js code in (small blocks). Here is the link for the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a9dnW/417/

jQuery

```
$("#test p").delay(1000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
$("#test2 p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
```

css

```
#test p {
opacity: 0;
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 21px;
text-align: center;
}
#test2 p {

opacity: 0;
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 21px;
text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/smallblocks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/kqsolo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
<div id="test2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just start the script after load content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#test p").delay(1000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
$("#test2 p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);

});
```

I tested it and it is working. If not, an error may be inside *smallblocks.js*. try to remove it and test to see if it's change something

Okay, your full code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<style>
    #test p {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #test2 p {

    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    }
</style>

 <div id="test"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
<div id="test2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test p").delay(1000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
    $("#test2 p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
});
</script>
```

Comment: But on YOUR page, you need to write it. Make a random html page and try this out. Of course it is working on jsFiddle, but if you gonna try on your own page, you need to write the full code

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But he provided a jsFiddle, so I guess he knows how to implemented in his own page.

Comment: Perfect.....I don't know why but I just completely spaced on the $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Cool ! Happy I could help you !
Don't forget to mark your question as SOLVED !

Answer (score 1):

Try fadeIn() and display: none; initially on your items

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/a9dnW/419/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#test p").fadeIn(700);
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#test2 p").fadeIn(700);
},3000);
```